Move vmlinuz-linux from / to /boot
I am running Arch Linux (dual booting with Windows). I recently had some boot issues, which lead me to chroot (live usb) and install the linux kernel again (pacman -S linux). This resulted in
vmlinuz-linux and initramfs-linux.img being located in the root directory now. But on the other hand the grub config file initialises a search in the boot directory.
Thus, currently I have to manually initialise the kernel everytime I boot my computer.
Should I move the two files (vmlinuz-linux and initramfs-linux.img) to the boot directory or is it preferable to change grub.cfg?
I am still quite new to arch, so I don't have any experience with either.
